# How to construct a field of order 8 and 9

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields

> Construct two fields, one of order 8 and one of order 9.

I only know that the field has 8 elements in the former case.

Comment: If you don't know anything more than that, where did you get this question from? It should, at the very least, have come at the end of a chapter describing what fields of size $p^m$ 'look like'...

Comment: Have you seen the construction of a field of order $4$? If you show us how you'd construct a field of order $4,$ maybe we can figure out from that how to make one of order $8$ or $9$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki  i get this question from my previous exam question paper..

Comment: @bof No i don't know.. you should help me.

Comment: @AmritSingh bof is trying to help you.  Being petulant and demanding is unlikely to elicit more useful replies.

Comment: So far you have shown no knowledge even remotely related to this question, and no effort. It is not our job to do your homework for you, or even to show you how it is done. Take some effort to actually learn the material first, make an attempt at this problem and show where you get stuck, and we may be able to help you, but as it stands there's simply nothing to be helped here.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki sorry brother. actual i've installed this app yesterday.i don't know how to write symbols in this app. so i'm sorry.

Comment: @AmritSingh Symbols? They aren't symbols, they're MathJax!

Answer (score 3):

Here is why Parcly's answer works: Let $F$ be a field (like $\mathbb R$, $\mathbb C$, $\mathbb F_p$,...).  Let $x$ be a variable, so that the powers $x^k$ are independent of each other.  Then you get a ring $F[x]$ of all polynomials with coefficients over the field $F$.  Note that $F[x]$ is a PID (and therefore a UFD) since it is a Euclidean domain via polynomial division with remainder.  The upshot here is that *irreducible elements in $F[x]$ generate maximal ideals*.

Since the polynomials $x^3 - x - 1$ and $x^2 + 1$ are irreducible over $\mathbb F_3$ (for they don't have roots), they are irreducible elements in $\mathbb F_3[x]$, whence the ideals they generate are maximal.  If $f$ is one of these polynomials (or something similar), then $\mathbb F_3[x]/(f)$ is a field by the ideal correspondence theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $8=2^3$ and $9=3^2$. The first thing that needs to be done is to find an irreducible cubic polynomial in GF(2) for the order-8 case, and an irreducible quadratic polynomial in GF(3) for the order-9 case; $x^3-x-1$ and $x^2+1$ will do.

Define $\alpha$ and $\beta$ with $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$ and $\beta^2=-1$. Then the elements of the order-8 field are $p+q\alpha+r\alpha^2$ where $p,q,r\in\{0,1\}$. The elements of the order-9 field are $s+t\beta$ with $s,t\in\{0,1,2\}$.